# Laplace transform of convolution

Tags: convolution, linear-control

I have been reading a book on automatic control and got stucked in the derivation of the laplace transform of the convolution integral. The autor says:

Laplace transform of the convolution of $g$ and $u$:
\begin{align*}
 &\hat{y}(s)=\int_{t=0}^\infty \left[ \int_{\tau =0}^\infty g(t-\tau) u(\tau)d\tau \right] e^{-st}dt
\end{align*}
Interchanching order of integrations:
\begin{align*}
 &\hat{y}(s)=\int_{t=0}^\infty \left[ \int_{\tau =0}^\infty g(t-\tau) u(\tau)d\tau \right] e^{-s(t-\tau)}e^{-s\tau}dt=\int_{\tau=0}^\infty \left[ \int_{t=0}^\infty g(t-\tau)e^{-s(t-\tau)}dt \right] u(\tau) e^{-s\tau}d\tau
\end{align*}

**My question is:** Is it correct to put the $e^{-s(t-\tau)}$ term in the inner integral in the way he dit it?.

I found another way of deriving this result wich I think is correct: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03sc-differential-equations-fall-2011/unit-iii-fourier-series-and-laplace-transform/transfer-system-and-weight-functions-greens-formula/MIT18_03SCF11_s30_5text.pdf

Thanks in advance, hope I'm not misunderstanding the procedure in the book.

Comment: If everything converges absolutely or uniformly, yes it is perfectly legitimate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so it doesn't matter that $e^{-s(t-\tau)}$ depends on $t$ when it is introduced inside the inner integral?, that is what makes me doubt.

Comment: If everything converges uniformly then $$\int_0^\infty (\int_0^\infty f(x,y)dx)dy=\lim_{A \to \infty} \int_0^A (\int_0^A f(x,y)dx)dy \\=\lim_{A \to \infty} \int_0^A (\int_0^A  f(x,y)dy)dx=\int_0^\infty (\int_0^\infty f(x,y)dy)dx$$

Comment: I think I got it:


$\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty f(t,\tau )d \tau g(t,\tau)dt=\lim_{A \to \infty} \int_0^A\int_0^A f(t,\tau)d \tau g(t,\tau)dt=\lim_{A \to \infty} \int_0^A\int_0^A f(t,\tau)dt g(t,\tau)d\tau=\lim_{A \to \infty} \int_0^A\int_0^A f(t,\tau)g(t,\tau)dt d\tau=\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty f(t,\tau)g(t,\tau)dt d\tau$


Is this true?. I don't want to be stubborn, but this will kill all my doubts.